# tablas relacionales en php

Tags: php, html, mysql

hola estoy intentando obtener los datos de un formulario en html e insertalos en mi base de datos donde tengo varias tablas relacionales, pero no se estan insertando correctamente me esta mandando la misma informacion de los campos name, app, apm y porcentaje para ambas tablas, pero yo estoy mandando informacion diferente. Una tabla es beneficiario y la otra marcha_1 Dejo mi codigo

```
// Manejar el formulario cuando se envía
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// Obtener datos del formulario (asegúrate de validar y limpiar los datos antes de 
usarlos)
$nombre = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["nombre"]);
$app = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["app"]);
$apm = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["apm"]);
$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$testigo1 = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["testigo1"]);
$testigo2 = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["testigo2"]);
$id_unidad = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['unidadAcademica']);
$porcentaje = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['porcentaje']);
$porcentaje_marcha_1 = isset($_POST['porcentaje_marcha_1']) ? $conn- 
>real_escape_string($_POST['porcentaje_marcha_1']) : null;


// Consulta de inserción para beneficiario
$sql_beneficiario = "INSERT INTO beneficiario (nombre, app, apm, fecha, testigo_1, testigo_2, aspabuap, buap, id_unidad) 
                     VALUES ('$nombre', '$app', '$apm', '$fecha', '$testigo1', '$testigo2', '', '', '$id_unidad')";

if ($conn->query($sql_beneficiario) === TRUE) {
    $id_beneficiario = $conn->insert_id;  // Obtener el ID generado automáticamente

    $_SESSION['success_message'] = "Datos de beneficiario insertados correctamente.";

    // Consulta de inserción para marcha_1
    $porcentaje_marcha_1 = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['porcentaje_marcha_1']);
    $sql_marcha_1 = "INSERT INTO marcha_1 (nombre, app, apm, porcentaje, id_beneficiario) 
                     VALUES ('$nombre', '$app', '$apm', '$porcentaje', '$id_beneficiario')";

    if ($conn->query($sql_marcha_1) === TRUE) {
        $_SESSION['success_message'] .= " Datos de marcha_1 insertados correctamente.";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['error_message'] = "Error al insertar datos en marcha_1: " . $conn->error;
    }

} else {
    $_SESSION['error_message'] = "Error al insertar datos en beneficiario: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Buenas, Angelica, bienvenida al sitio. No entiendo bien tu problema. ¿A qué te refieres con que estás mandando datos distintos? En ambos inserts estás usando los mismos valores, lo que tengan las variables $nombre, $app, $apm, ... No parece que las cambies de valor entre una y otra instrucción de insert.

Comment: Sin mencionar que no tienes ningún campo o variable llamada **name**. Y yo no se si a este modelo yo lo llamaría "tablas relacionales" ya que no tienen el Modelo de Entidad Relación en ello, son tablas normales, "vinculadas" por campos. Pero me reservo la idea de si se le puede llamar una DB Relacional o no...